# trabalhar com dados inseridos numa mesma linha em pyhton

Tags: python, while

Olá!

Estou trabalhando em um programa que precisa realizar cálculos com vários números inseridos pelo usuário, todos de uma vez só. Por exemplo, se o usuário inserir "123 456 768 986", eu preciso ser capaz de fazer cálculos entre 986 e 123 posteriormente. Como posso fazer isso?

Minhas ideias iniciais incluíam criar variáveis para cada número digitado com base na sua posição na sequência, mas não tenho certeza se isso é possível.

Além disso, é importante observar que não posso utilizar o recurso de lista em Python.

Agradeço desde já pela ajuda!

Comment: pesquise aqui mesmo no site por python e split. veja um exemplo [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/333423/70)

Comment: é possível fazer isso apenas com while, if, cont, else e os operadores matemáticos (+, - , //, % etc)? é exigência da aula e simplesmente não vejo saída apenas com isso

Comment: Possível é, mas não faz muito sentido. A quantidade de números digitadas será sempre 4?

Comment: há um mínimo de 5 números digitados, mas não há um máximo. O que vc sugere?

Comment: Palpite: `primeiro, segundo, terceiro, quarto, *resto = map(int, input().split())`. O `split` é para separar por espaço, e `map`/`int` é para converter cada um para número. Assim pega os quatro primeiros, cada um em uma variável, e os demais ficam em `resto`. Aí vc usa cada variável como bem entender. Não sei onde se encaixaria o `while`, `if` etc, quem sabe se tivesse o enunciado completo, daria para sugerir algo mais assertivo.